# cannot find error in mysql code

Tags: mysql

I've been staring at this for ages and i cannot figure out what is wrong with this code

```
CREATE TABLE `faults` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Reported_by` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`Company` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Reporters_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Department` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Error_Detail` text,
`user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `faults_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
```

the fault is on the last line

this is the error it gives me which isn't very helpful:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11

can anybody spot my mistake??

Comment: no closing bracket? CREATE TABLE `faults` (...

Comment: Prob the needed parenthesis `REFERENCES 'users' ('id'));`

Comment: @ldrumm that's an answer, not a comment ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, a little formatting helps find your mistake (missing closing parenthesis). I would also recommend being more consistent with your column naming. Don't mix capitalization with lower case and underscores. I would suggest camel case.

```
CREATE TABLE `faults` 
  ( 
     `id`              INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `reported_by`     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
     `company`         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `reporters_email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
     `department`      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `error_detail`    TEXT, 
     `user_id`         INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     KEY `user_id` (`user_id`), 
     CONSTRAINT `faults_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) 
  ); <-- missing
```

Comment: Thanks its always something so simple, and got rid of the caps thanks for advice on caps

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have missed a closing bracket.
`CREATE TABLE faults (` is not closed before your terminating semicolon on line 11 as MySQL is complaining about.

Add the closing bracket and you should be fine:
    `REFERENCES 'users' ('id'));`

To more easily notice errors such as these, you should use a text editor that supports bracket and brace matching.  All good programmer's editors will do this.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev according to whom?  They are synonymous as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) would disagree with you.

Comment: @ldrumm I see. I've always associated with `[` but guess I'm wrong. Learn something every day.

Comment: The square bracket `[` can be called 'bracket', but on its own, the word bracket is synonymous with both mathematical parentheses as well as square brackets used for indices in most prgramming languages.  I agree that in the context of my answer this seems a bit flowery, so I'll edit my post.

Comment: i usually use n++ when editing but was using phpmyadmin and also working off putty as was meant to be a quick edit.